# Custom sorter for Rally rallygridboard

Tags: rally

I have a **rallygridboard** that shows portfolio items. I want to create my custom sorter for columns.

Is it possible and how?

Comment: Can you be slightly more specific about what you're trying to do?  What type of custom sorter?

Comment: I think I have different problem. Maybe you can help or suggest something. This is my custom table - http://prntscr.com/hmm4cl. When I try to sort table by Owner (just email) - sorting doesn't work at all. I looked at JSON response and found that sorting works well for simple data time like Name or ID, but doesn't work for complex objects like Owner (it's an object with nestead fields). What can I do to have sorting work for complex fields like Owner?

Comment: Hmm, I would think it should be sorting owner by DisplayName- is that not the behavior you're seeing?